# Align contents vertically in mobile version

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am pretty new to bootstrap and the way it works, I have been trying to align the contents inside the website vertically in the mobile version, the current output is shown below:
Current output:

[image]

How to I align the contacts section vertically, such that its just underneath the news section and above the education section

any help would be appreciated

The HTML with bootstrap code I have so far:

```html
<div class="container px-4 py-5" id="featured-3">
  <h2 class="pb-2 border-bottom">About Inholland</h2>
  <div class="row g-4 py-5 row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-3">
    <div class="feature col">
      <div class="feature-icon bg-#e3027f bg-gradient">
        <!--<svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em"><use xlink:href="#collection" /></svg>-->
        <svg style="color: #fff" class="bi text-white" width="1em" height="1em">
          <use xlink:href="#collect-icon" class="bi bi-collection"></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <h2>News</h2>
      <p>View up to date news about inholland organisation and its employees</p>
      <a style="color: #e3027f" href="#" class="icon-link">
        read more
        <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em">
          <use xlink:href="#chevron-right" />
        </svg>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="feature col">
      <div class="feature-icon bg-#e3027f bg-gradient">
        <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em">
          <use xlink:href="#people-circle" />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <h2>Contacts</h2>
      <p>
        Learn more about our organisations chairman, faculty members and
        contacts to reach if you have any issues
      </p>
      <a style="color: #e3027f" href="#" class="icon-link">
        read more
        <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em">
          <use xlink:href="#chevron-right" />
        </svg>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="feature col">
      <div class="feature-icon bg-#e3027f bg-gradient">
        <!--<svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em"><use xlink:href="#toggles2" /></svg>-->
        <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em">
          <use xlink:href="#toggle-icon" />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <h2>Education</h2>
      <p>
        Explore various types of courses provided by inholland university in
        different types of faculties
      </p>
      <a style="color: #e3027f" href="#" class="icon-link bg-#e3027f">
        read more
        <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em">
          <use xlink:href="#chevron-right" />
        </svg>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Class="align-middle", change the alignment of elements with the vertical-alignment utilities. Please note that vertical-align only affects inline, inline-block, inline-table, and table cell elements. If its a block type, you might try something like margin: 0 auto; (CSS)

Comment: I copy pasted your code onto https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/sk2um0eL/, and it works fine; news, contacts and education are stacked vertically when the screen is `xs` to `md`. I guess there is something else messing your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Add `align-items-end` in container row:

```
<div class="row g-4 py-5 row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-3 align-items-end">
```